# Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, jndi

I am getting the above exception, and I don't know why.
Here is some more information:

```
Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/staffing_2014'
```

I am using Spring. In the Spring application context, I have the following dataSource:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
    jndi-name="jdbc/StaffingDB"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

It seems to read the database URL and credentials OK from tomcat's `context.xml`:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/StaffingDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="xxx" password="yyy" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/staffing_2014"/>
```

Before anyone suggests Googling it, I have. The obvious answers I've found have been:

- Database URL malformed? - checked and OK.
- MySQL driver in classpath? Yes- jar is in `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib`

Any other suggesions?

EDIT - way down the bottom:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:279)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
```

Comment: You did create the database "staffing_2014"?

Comment: Is there a specific Exception being thrown (e.g. `NoClassDefFoundException` or `ClassNotFoundException`)?

Comment: @RaunakAgarwal yes the database certainly exists

Comment: @NickJ can you write a simple JSP inside a separate clean web app that uses the JNDI resource jdbc/StaffingDB and tries to connect to the db as a test? If it works then the issue is with the Spring layer

Comment: If you are using windows make sure the lib directory path is added to the Classpath variable in the Environment Variables.  If linux, the lib directory path should be set in the classpath in tomcat6 conf file.

Comment: @DavidBrossard - simple JSP written and works. That narrows things down a bit

Comment: @NickJ check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354997/no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost3306-test - are you hitting the same issue?

Comment: Exactly where is that <Resource ... /> definition?

Comment: Thanks to the link posted by @DavidBrossard I was able to get it working, but it breaks if I restart the app or redeploy it using `mvn tomcat:redeploy`. I have to then restart tomcat to get it working again.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Tomcat are you using? In some Tomcats (T5), `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` may not be the right location. You have to put the driver in Tomcat's endorsed folder which could be

- TOMCAT_HOME/endorsed or
- TOMCAT_HOME/shared/lib

Check your Tomcat setup.

Comment: The version is 6.0.35. The endorsed and shared directories do not exist. The lib directory is correct according to the Tomcat JNDI HowTo at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: I think it's better to put the .jar file in webapps/$yourAppName/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: I had it there originally. I wanted to move it out to try and avoid a memory leak when redeploying.

Comment: You can only put the jdbc driver in webapp/WEB-INF/lib if you define the jndi resource within the web app. So if your context.xml is in Tomcat's conf/ folder then you need to add the library to Tomcat's lib folder.